Querying PST files and exporting results
I have a folder of outlook .pst email archives that I need to query for a subject and export the results as a pst or other format that results in collection of emails/messages to be shared with others.
I can extract and query the emails using the code below, which results in a tibble/df that contains fields for to, from, subject, body, etc..., however I am at a loss on how to export these results out to an email or message format that can be shared with others.
library(freepst)
library(tidyverse)


##get filenames
PST_FOLDER <- "C:/Path/To/Backup/Folder"


pst_files <- tibble(FILE_NAME=list.files(PST_FOLDER, ".pst", full.names = T, recursive = T)) %>% filter(!str_detect(FILE_NAME, ".tmp"))


##extract emails---
read_pst_source <- function(FILE_NAME){read_pst(FILE_NAME) %>% mutate(Source=FILE_NAME)}

poss_read_pst <- possibly(read_pst_source, otherwise = "Error")


PST_DATA<-pst_files$FILE_NAME %>%  map(~poss_read_pst(.)) %>% reduce(rbind)
##returns a  tibble with to, from, subject, body etc... as fields

##search emails

SUBJECT_A_EMAILS <- PST_DATA %>% filter(if_any(everything(),str_detect,coll ("Subject A", ignore_case = T)))



##export emails


SUBJECT_A_EMAILS %>% ????



Having data on hand I would send e-mail from R - have a look on https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sendmailR/index.html. If you wish to filter out email by field please have a look on subset() function or dplyr::filter().
